# Maintain usercontrol state across pages

Tags: asp.net

I want to maintain user control state across two to three pages,

how can I do it?

that two to three pages have same user control(with out session)

*flow*

I have two pages one for listing page, when clicking on any listing goes to detail page so with these two pages left side I am using search user control.

Answer (score 1):

Server.Transfer.  You can either stuff values in the HttpContext before transferring or refer to the previous page once transferred.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the data that you want available on the different pages into a context cache:

```
Context.Cache.Add(CacheName,
                    CacheData,
                    null,
                    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                    new System.TimeSpan(0, 30, 0),
                    System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.High,
                    null);
```

I'm usually concatenating the data into a delimited string before I add it to the cache and identify the cache based on a user id and it's purpose.